# Converting byte array to image Android

Tags: android, encoding, arrays, asmx, decode

I have a service running which return a byte array. The service is written is C# (asmx file). I request the service to send back an image that is encoded with MemoryStream in the service and is received by the application in byte array. The next thing I did is that I converted the byte array as follows:

```
 Object o = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("ImageTransformationResult");

  String result = o.toString();
  byte[] data = result.getBytes();

  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

  SaveImageToSdCard(bmp);
```

The image that is saved is empty. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I found out that the problem may be that the encoding used on the server is not the same as the decoding I am using.

Comment: there is no chance `o.toString().getBytes()` represents an image.

Comment: no i ve tried that solution and its not working for me! the bmp is remaining null.

Comment: what should i do then to remove the `o.toString().getBytes()`

Comment: I resolved this using `byte[] data = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);`